# How to create grid layout when i have only one tag in html where i display data from database?

Tags: html, css, mysql, jsp

I don't know if my question is well formulated so i will show you my code. This is my jsp:

```
    <body>
    <c:forEach var="book" items="${book_list}">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-item">${book.title}</div>//Multiple different books are displayed here
                <div class="grid-item">${book.price}$</div>//Multiple different prices
            </div>
            <form action="addToCart" method="GET">
                <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
            </form>                                                               
    </c:forEach>
</body>
```

As you can see i have for each tag where i traverse through book_list(from database) and display their title and price in two div tags. I want to make grid layout and put items(books) in grid. So i google how to do that and every example was like this:

```
   <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  </div>
```

Here each item have a div tag. How can i put my books in grid layout when i have one tag but multiple items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two divs inside your `<div class="grid-item">` for name and price and design them separately . So ,your  **jsp**  code will look like below :

```
<div class="grid-container">
 <c:forEach var="book" items="${book_list}">
      <div class="grid-item">
         <div class="name">${book.title}</div>
         <div class="price">${book.price}$</div>
         <div class="cart">
         <form action="addToCart" method="GET">
         <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
        </form></div>
    </div>
   </c:forEach>
</div>
```

**Demo Code** :

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  /*space between colums*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /*will show 3 item */
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.name {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}

.price {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: orange;
}

.cart {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="name">Item name</div>
    <div class="price"> 150 $</div>
    <div class="cart">
      <form action="addToCart" method="GET">
        <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="name">Item name</div>
    <div class="price">150 $</div>
    <div class="cart">
      <form action="addToCart" method="GET">
        <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="name">Item name</div>
    <div class="price">150 $</div>
    <div class="cart">
      <form action="addToCart" method="GET">
        <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CSS grid styling in order to display each column. Displaying multiple items in each column will result in a grid styling:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Title-1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">prop-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Title-2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">prop-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="grid-item">Title-3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">prop-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are other ways of getting similar effects, such as HTML tables.

Comment: Thanks Yair, that's not what i want though. I want in one column to have Title 1 and below prop-1, then next column Title 2 and below prop-2 etc. Do you know maybe how?

Comment: The styling should answer your needs now. check it out.